# How to identify the provided hostname/URL is private in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, security, npm

I am looking for a way/NPM package to validate for private/local/bad addresses the entered hostname coming as an input to my REST endpoint before storing it in the DB.
This is required to avoid SSRF attacks.
So far, I am only filtering out the hostnames based on the regex. If I find that the hostname starts with an IP, I block it but there are certain cases where this fix won't work like loopback addresses. I couldn't find any NPM library that does all these validations. There were a few packages but they expect IP as input and that I am already filtering. I even moved from regex to the `ipaddr.js` package as that regex was getting complex and difficult to understand.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here on how to validate the URL for private/loopback address?

Answer (score 2):

If one of your machines is going to do requests to URL that are defined by a user, and you want to avoid that people enter addresses in your private network, you need to resolve the hostname first and figure out the target ip.

You can't know if a hostname targets a private address by just looking at the hostname, because I can register 'blabla.com' and have it resolve to `10.0.0.1`.

The best practice for this stuff is to make a dedicated box that is completely isolated from your private network to do all the requests.

Comment: At this point, we can't really create a separate isolated box to process such requests. Is there any alternative for this? I understood your point but we can't really implement it as of now

Comment: I am planning to make use of `dns` module of NodeJS to resolve the hostname to an IP and then figure out whether it is private or not using ipaddrjs or is-loopback-addr NPM packages

Comment: An isolated box is the _right_ way, and resolving addresses is the workaround.

Comment: @VermaAman - Keep in mind that you also have to either not follow redirects or also apply your same IP address protection on redirected URLs.  So, if they give you a legit outside domain/IP and then you go make a request to that and it redirects to 10.0.0.x or 192.168.x.y, you have to retest the redirect location too.

Comment: @jfriend00 @Evert I resolved the hostname to IP using the `dns` package and now I am using `ip` library to check whether it is private or not (`ip.isPrivate()`). So far it is working for my test cases. Is it missing any corner cases?

Comment: @jfriend00 made a good point, you probably don't want to follow redirects.